# Изменить шрифт в ActionBar

Tags: android

Подключил в MainActivity кастомный шрифт

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BeeskneesC.otf");
```

Как теперь можно изменить стиль шрифта ActionBar на кастомный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно либо таким способом

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
textView.setTypeface(face);
```

либо таким способом

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(s);
```